# How to I replace all chars and numbers in string except several chars

Tags: c#, string, replace, char

how to I replace all characters and numbers in string except several chars, for example "f", "a", "l" to avoid somthing like this:

```
String str = "replace different characters except several";
Console.WriteLine("Input: " + str);
str = str.Replace('a', '.').Replace('b', '.').Replace('c', '.');
Console.WriteLine("Output: " + str);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be using `Linq` and replacing every character except those in excluded list.

```
char[] excluded = new char[] {'f', 'a', 'l'};       
var output = new string(str.Select(x=> excluded.Contains(x)? x:'.').ToArray());
```

Check this [`demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gD7Djy)

Comment: Given Code and Demo Code are different! Change demo code also buddy :)

Comment: what is the difference? it is same.

Comment: In Demo .Dump(); is there. Please check it.

Comment: Yeah that is to output to `console`, here it is not required.

Comment: But it is nice one!

Comment: @Hari Prasad very useful for my case

Answer (score 2):

Use [Regex](https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex) for these kind of scenarios:

```
String str = "replace different characters except several";
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[^fal]", "."); //Replace all with "." EXCEPT f,a,l
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

> Output:- "...la.....ff........a.a..................al"

Comment: Create this one @"[^fal]" as a meaning full words. Example string pattern="@"[^fal]"";

Comment: @JerryGoyal it is also good answer, works well, but for my case better use with list below